# Jenkins error while importing "github.com/sparrc/go-ping" library

Tags: go

I am using `github.com/sparrc/go-ping` library , while I posted it in gerrit, jenkins posted `-1` and complains `cannot find package "github.com/sparrc/go-ping" in any of:`

How can I overcome this?

Comment: You need to `vendor` the library or make sure it's go getted in the `GOPATH` on the machine where Jenkins is running.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming `GOPATH` is correctly set in your Jenkins server. You have to do `go get github.com/sparrc/go-ping` before doing the go build.